# Как получить переменную из функции обработчика события?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```js
    <div>
        <form action="startpage.html" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="checkbox" id="subjNumCheckbox"/>Количество предметов
        <input type="text" name="dealAmount" id="dealAmount" label="Максимальная сумма договора"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn">
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
    var subjNum = '// КОЛИЧЕСТВО ПРЕДМЕТОВ ЛИЗИНГА\n' +
                    '\tЕсли СтрокаПредмет.КалькуляторЛизинга.СуммаДоговора <= ' + subjNumField + 'тогда\n' +
                    '\t\tЕсли КоличествоПредметов > 2 тогда\n' +
                    '\t\t\tРезультат = Ложь;\n'
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            if ($("#subjNumCheckbox").is(':checked') == true) {
                  code_text += subjNum;
                  $('textarea').text(code_text);
            }
       });
       $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
                subjNumField = $('#dealAmount').val();
       })
});
</script>
```

Как добавить переменную `subjNumField` к строке?

Comment: Вот так выглядит моя html страница https://imgur.com/xszXKzg . При выборе checkbox'а появляется 1) subjNumField. Туда записывается число. Отправляю это через 2) submitBtn. Снова выбираю этот checkbox. Нажимаю на 3), и в 4) должен появиться новый текст subjNum

Comment: сюда в вопрос добавьте фрагменты страницы с вашим скриптом. а то не у всех есть доступ к вашей ссылке и не понятно, что такое 1, 2, 3 и 4 (некие действия пользователя на странице?)

Comment: Код будет слишком длинным. Буду прикреплять по-фрагментно

Comment: в  исходный запрос вставьте

Comment: Я так думаю, проблема в асинхронности.

Comment: у вас проблема в архитектуре решения, вы отправляете форму по клику на кнопку, все данные стираются, если вам нужно хранение клиентских переменных, то нужно использовать куки или локальное хранилище

Comment: @Konst, спасибо вам большое! Попробую копать в ту сторону

Answer (score 0):

Объявление переменных по стандарту `ES6`:

```
let subjNum = '';
let subjNumField = '';
```

Добавить можно так (конкатинация):

```
subjNum = subjNum + subjNumField
```

В вашем случае создадим функцию, и вызовем её по наступлению события.

Ваш пример:

```js
let subjNum = '';

function addText(text){
  return '// КОЛИЧЕСТВО ПРЕДМЕТОВ ЛИЗИНГА\n' +
  '\tЕсли СтрокаПредмет.КалькуляторЛизинга.СуммаДоговора <= ' + text +
  'тогда\n' +
  '\t\tЕсли КоличествоПредметов > 2 тогда\n' +
  '\t\t\tРезультат = Ложь;\n';
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
    subjNum = addText($('#dealAmount').val());
    
  })
})
```

Comment: "subjNum = subjNum + subjNumField" разве это вставит значение subjNumField именно в то место, которое мне нужно? Извините, если вопрос глупый, но я совсем не javascript-программист

Comment: @Офисный_рабочий Подправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
            alert(getAlert($('#dealAmount').val()));
        });
    });
function getAlert(deal) {
    var s = (deal == null || deal == undefined) ? '': deal.toString();
    return '// КОЛИЧЕСТВО ПРЕДМЕТОВ ЛИЗИНГА\n' +
            '\tЕсли СтрокаПредмет.КалькуляторЛизинга.СуммаДоговора <= ' + s + ' тогда\n' +
            '\t\tЕсли КоличествоПредметов > 2 тогда\n' +
            '\t\t\tРезультат = Ложь;\n';
}
```

- alert только для демонстрации
- вызывайте getAlert() в том месте, где вам нужно получить новое сообщение

Comment: с alert'ом это срабатывает, но мне нужно, чтобы потом это можно было записать в другое текстовое поле (если убрать alert, в другом текстовом поле у меня выходит #deal# вместо значения)

Comment: полный код страницы покажите в своем вопросе, тогда сможем помочь